# How to display windows of two different firefox profiles under different dash icons?

Tags: firefox, launcher, icons, unity-dash, .desktop

I created two distinct .desktop launchers for two different firefox profiles:

- profile1.desktop

  ```
  sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop

      [Desktop Entry]
      Name=profile1
      Keywords=profile1
      Exec=firefox -P -no-remote profile1
      Terminal=false
      X-MultipleArgs=false
      Type=Application
      Icon=profile1.png
      StartupNotify=true
      StartupWMClass=profile1
  ```
- profile2.desktop

  ```
  sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/firefox_profile2.desktop

  [Desktop Entry]
  Name=profile2
  Keywords=profile2
  Exec=firefox -P -no-remote profile2
  Terminal=false
  X-MultipleArgs=false
  Type=Application
  Icon=profile2.png
  StartupNotify=true
  StartupWMClass=profile2
  ```

I then added each desktop launcher to the dashboard (via right-click > add to favorites).
I am able to launch each profile from the respective launcher-icon in the dashboard.
So far so good.
However, w*hen profile2 is launched, its window will be listed/collected under the profile1 (default) firefox dash icon*, which can get quite confusing.

I would really like to **display and collect windows from different firefox profiles under different dash items** (i.e. icons in the dashboard).
I suspect the problem is - since both .dekstop launchers execute different processes of the same /usr/bin/firefox command - that they are automatically collected under some firefox dash icon...

Does anyone have an idea how to resolve this issue?

Comment: I have no idea if this will work, but try this: create a second executable that is merely a symbolic link to the first one `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/firefox /usr/bin/firefox2` and use `firefox2` in the Exec line of `profile2.desktop`.

Comment: Thanks @Jos, but unfortunately creating a symbolic link and invoking that one from the exec line in the .dekstop file does not help: The profile.2 windows are still collected under the profile.1 dash icon. To me this is quite frustrating; why is it not possible to collect windows from different firefox processes under different dash items...? :/

Answer (score 0):

I have two firefox profiles on my 16.04 box with two different icons in the dashboard.

What I did was create two desktop short cuts.  For the first one the command to run it is `firefox %u`.  For the second one the command to run it is `firefox -no-remote -P ScriptUser`.  When I launch these I get two different instances of Firefox.  I have pinned each to the dashboard and given each a different name for ease of identification.  This works for me.  Now I'm trying to establish how to do the same thing, but in cairo-dock.  So far that's proving less easy.

Hope that helps.

Comment: nice work! How did you set the commands to run it? Did you make a new `.desktop` file and edit it yourself?

Comment: I created it using firefox -profilemanager which you can start from the terminal provided you don't have any instances of firefox already open.

Comment: Hi @Stevepar , I tried to follow Your instructions, but it seems, when I launch the different .desktop links, the resulting application windows are again collected under the same dash icon. Could You maybe further explain Your approach?