# Microsoft Edge multiple profiles/desktop applications

Tags: .desktop

For my new Ubuntu 22.04 setup, I have installed Microsoft Edge and configured it with two profiles: Personal (Default) and Work (Profile 1). I have hence created two desktop applications in `$HOME/.local/share/applications`: `microsoft-edge.desktop` where, in the `Exec` field, I have added the command line option `--profile-directory="Default"`; and `microsoft-edge-work.desktop` where I have added `--profile-directory="Profile 1"` similarly.

This setup was working yesterday that if I click 'Microsoft Edge' then it will open a personal window under that dash icon, and if I click 'Microsoft Edge (Work)' it will open a work window under this icon. However, today, I don't know whether because I was changing something during the setup or edge was updated or something else, if I click 'Microsoft Edge (Work)', it will open a work window under the 'Microsoft Edge' icon, and so both profiles are mixed in that single one.

I have tried to renamed the former from 'Microsoft Edge' to something like 'Personal', but now both of them are mixing tabs in a new 'Microsoft Edge' icon instead, rather than keeping windows in their respective icons. This is frustrating since somehow it did actually work, and it is certainly achievable in other browsers [firefox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/915180/how-to-display-windows-of-two-different-firefox-profiles-under-different-dash-ic).

Comment: Hi Mike, did you find a solution? I have the same issue.